# Android: Process.myTid() VS Thread.currentThread().getId()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have simple `Activity` that calls `AsyncTask`, so I print some id's regarding `Proces` and `Thread`:

```
From onCreate android.os.Process.myUid(): 10137
From onCreate android.os.Process.myPid(): 29776
From onCreate android.os.Process.myTid(): 29776
From onCreate Thread.currentThread().getId(): 1
/****************************************************************/
From Async doInBackground android.os.Process.myUid(): 10137
From Async doInBackground android.os.Process.myPid(): 29776
From Async doInBackground android.os.Process.myTid(): 30426
From Async doInBackground Thread.currentThread().getId(): 12556
```

1. `Uid` is same because its [app-specific sandbox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#myUid())
2. Similar with `Pid`: [Each app is one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#myPid()) `Process`
3. 3rd line in `onCreate` same as `Pid` because it's the `UIThread` and in Android OS as based on Linux we know that issue regarding `Process` is actually `Thread` etc... And in the `Async` the `ThreadId` is different because `AsyncTask` runs on different `Thread` rather then the `UIThread`

The thing I'm struggling to understand is `Thread.currentThread().getId()`. What I expect is to get same id as `Thread.currentThread().getId()` for the same execution environment. e.g. for `onCreate` I want lines 3,4 to be same (29776), and for `Async` I expect lines 3,4 to be the same (30426). What is going on here?

Thanks,

Comment: What `AsyncTask`'s method do you log the IDs from?

Comment: @Onik `onCreate` (the Activity) is calling regular `new SomeTask().execute();` Which is regular Android `AsyncTask`

Comment: Sure! Do you log the IDs? If so, I understand that one of the methods you log is `Activity`'s `onCreate()`. What is the other one (in `AsyncTask`)?

Comment: @Onik I think I got it... `Log.e("Tag", getId...)` inside `doInBackground` the use of `Log` is the root source?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Very interesting question by the OP and I decided to dig (love open source).

**The short answer is:** they're different because they're different, because they were never meant to be the same.

- `Process.myTid()` is the linux thread ID
- `Thread.getId()` is a simple sequential `long` number.

But the short answer is boring, so let's explore where the answer comes from (links in the answer points to the relevant source codes).

In [`Process.myTid()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Process.java#780), you'll see that is simply calls from [`Os.gettid()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os.html#gettid()) that in itself calls a native method on [`Libcore`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/android/system/Os.java#Os.gettid%28%29) for that method is below:

```
public static int gettid() { return Libcore.os.gettid(); }
```

furthermore the docs for `Os.gettid();` you'll find a link to [Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html)

> gettid() returns the caller's thread ID (TID).  In a single-threaded
>          process, the thread ID is equal to the process ID (PID, as returned
>          by getpid(2)).  In a multithreaded process, all threads have the same
>          PID, but each one has a unique TID.

- That means, `Process.myTid()` returns the thread ID as given by the Linux kernel.

On the other hand [`Thread.getId()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.getId%28%29) is simply returning a `long`. This long is assigned during `init(...)` as [`tid = nextThreadId();`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Thread.java#409). Then the last piece of this puzzle, below is the code for [`nextThreadId()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.nextThreadID%28%29)

```
/* For generating thread ID */
private static long threadSeqNumber;

private static synchronized long More ...nextThreadID() {
    return ++threadSeqNumber;
}
```

- That means, `Thread.getId()` is simply a "java layer" static long being auto-increment for each thread.