# Why does this code give this output for the thread's priority?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, linux-kernel, android-threading

I have the following code `onCreate()`

```
Log.d(TAG, "Setting priority background");  
Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);  
Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
Log.d(TAG, Process.getThreadPriority(Process.myTid()) + " - myTid() " + Process.myTid() + " Thread.getId() = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
// start a thread here
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            Log.d(TAG, " In new thread");
            Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": " +   Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
            Log.d(TAG, Process.getThreadPriority(Process.myTid()) + " - myTid() " + Process.myTid() + "Thread.getId() = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

}
```

The output is:

```
Setting priority background  
1: 5  
10 - myTid() 8798 Thread.getId() = 1  

In new thread  
7534: 10  
-8 - myTid() 8819 Thread.getId() = 7534
```

Can someone please explain:
1) Even though I set `setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);` the log in the next line shows priority `5`. Why?
2) Where is the `-8` coming from in the output for the priority of the second thread?
3) Where is the `10` for the new thread coming from too?

**Update:**
If I remove the line `Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);`
the output remains the same

Answer (score 2):

Reading [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND), `THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` delegates a lower than normal priority to the task on that thread.

Taking information from [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/exploring-android-thread-priority-5d0542eebbd1), using `Thread.setPriority()` contains a value from MIN_PRIORITY(1) to MAX_PRIORITY(10) *whereas* `Process.setThreadPriority()` supports value from -20 to 19.

The image below shows the Android Scheduler and the Linux Scheduler and their priority levels. Calling `Process` and `Thread` to get thread priority will return two diffrent values as they are two different schedulers, like in your logs.

[image]

Update:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171734/android-process-mytid-vs-thread-currentthread-getid) post provided some insight into this:

- Process.myTid() is the linux thread ID
- Thread.getId() is a simple
  sequential long number.

*"Thread.getId() is simply a "java layer" static long being auto-increment for each thread."*

ThreadID is not equal to ProcessID.

However, casting the long to int and providing the ThreadID to the Process returns an expcted value `Process.getThreadPriority((int) Thread.currentThread().getId())`.

Comment: That mapping does not explain where the value `-8` came from though I believe

Comment: Also as per that mapping `5 <=> 0` but 10 is printed

Comment: Updated with some more info.

Comment: Thanks for the update but I am not using `Process.getThreadPriority((int) Thread.currentThread().getId())`. How is this called?

Comment: I mean I am not doing `Process.getThreadPriority((int) Thread.currentThread().getId())` anywhere. Why is that affecting something?

Comment: `However, casting the long to int and providing the ThreadID to the Process ` where is this happening?

Comment: No, i was saying thats what i did. I dont know anymore without searching more into it. Seems like Process.myTid is switching threads at some point? It seems like its a pool of threads rather than a single thread.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that in the Thread class the priority is only updated if someone calls the setPriority method!!! So the Thread class does not "see" the change of the priority happening from Process.setThreadPriority!!!! Those don't sync! So this explains why the priorities returned by the 2 APIs are different.